# how to run a simple java program in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

[here is the image of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88rGr.png) I am having problem in running the above program in android studio please help. Android studio is not giving the desired result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code which is not working for you?

Comment: What problem you are having? What is your expected result? Share your source code and problem i.e. detaile info

Comment: Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine after clean and rebuild the project. thanks for your help guys.